# How to output matfiles in Mathematica?

Tags: export, files-and-directories

I am new to Mathematica, if there is anything wrong, do not hesitate to tell me?

```
WW1 = {{0,0},{0,0},{0.532089,0.434531},{0,0},{0.812587,0.278014}};
WW2 = {{0,0},{0,0},{0.273867,0.365045},{0,0},{0.126252,0.646143}};
```

I would like to know how to export the data into Matfile? The I can use Matlab to plot for the figure for consistency.

I use the code:

```
Export["data.mat", {"WW1", "WW2"}]
```

However, it does not work and reports an error:

> "{"WW1", "WW2"} cannot be exported to the ("MAT") format."

Could you please help me fix it?

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MAT.html

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
Export["data1.mat", WW1]
Export["data2.mat", WW2]
```

Is that what you want?

Or combined them into a single matrix using Mathematica, then export the whole matrix. But without the double quotes.